# Stop scrolling at last object in Scroll View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

[image: scroll view issue]

As you can see in the attached image if I keep scrolling past the last object in my scrollview I can keep scrolling and then see the background. Is there a way to limit this in xcode so you can't scroll past the last object in the scroll view?

I'm new to xcode and did try researching this issue though I believe my terminology is impacting this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will need to set the `scrollView.contentSize` size so that it fits around all your objects in the scroll view. if you have a way to determine which object is the lowest then you can use its origin + height to determine  the height of the content size.

```
float maxHeight = 0;

for(UIView *v in [scrollView subviews]){
    if(v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height > maxHeight)
        maxHeight = v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height;
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, maxHeight+5);
```