# How can I get a UIScrollView to scroll vertically with dynamic amount of subviews inside of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, uiview, uiscrollview

So I have a `UIScrollView` and within that, I'd like to add some subviews, currently I have around 5 or 6, they are about `90px` in height, so obviously when it gets to the bottom of the screen, I'd like it to scroll so you can see more, if that makes sense.

Below is what I have already, `parentView` being the `UIScrollView`, `newResult` being a row I'd like to append. `GSResultBlock` is a class that extends `UIView`.

```
    for (NSObject * person in resultsCollection) {
      CGRect resultBlockFrame   = CGRectMake(0, resultCount, parentView.bounds.size.width, 90);
      GSResultBlock * newResult = [[GSResultBlock alloc] initWithFrame:resultBlockFrame];

      [parentView addSubview:[newResult getResultBlock]];

      [newResult release];

      resultCount = resultCount + 95;
}
```

Keep in mind that foreach `newResult` there will be additional subviews in there also, for example, a `UIImageView` ect.. (They are not included in the code above though)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `setContentOffset:animated:`

Comment: I'm not too sure, maybe, how exactly would I use that?

Comment: it's a method of `UIScrollView`. You pass the `CGPoint` and it scrolls to that point.

Comment: I gave it a try, but it only scrolls once, after that it stays still.

Comment: You should also increase the contentSize of the scroll view when you are adding new views inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` using something like:

```
[parentView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(parentView.frame), resultCount)];
```

after the end of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197392/1219956)

```
float maxHeight = 0;

for(UIView *v in [scrollView subviews]){
    if(v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height > maxHeight)
        maxHeight = v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height;
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, maxHeight+5);
```

once you have put all your views into  the scroll view, run this and it will make your scrollview scroll the right amount

Comment: He doesn't need to run that loop.  He's already got the size of his content calculated and stored in `resultCount`.

Comment: ah i see, not sure what he is asking then

Comment: I think you have the right idea and setting the contentSize like you suggested should solve @harry-lawrence's issue.  I'm just saying that he doesn't need to go and recalculate the content height because he already has calculated it in the code he posted in his question.